# viewElements Fails To Fire in Custom Field Formatter

Tags: plugins

Using the code, below, in *my_module* in the path *my_module/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/DateRangeSpecialFormatter.php* the format appears both in the Views field dialog and the content type manage display dialog, but having selected the format, clearing cache and either loading the page or reloading the view preview, viewElements() does not fire.

The formatter is a clone of a datetime_range formatter.

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter;

use Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemListInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\DateTimeCustomFormatter;
use Drupal\datetime_range\DateTimeRangeTrait;

/**
 * Plugin implementation of the Special daterange formatter.
 *
 * @FieldFormatter(
 *   id = "daterange_special",
 *   label = @Translation("Special date range formatter"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "daterange",
 *   }
 * )
 */
class DateRangeSpecialFormatter extends DateTimeCustomFormatter {

  use DateTimeRangeTrait;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function defaultSettings() {
    return [
        'separator' => '|',
      ] + parent::defaultSettings();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function settingsSummary() {
    $summary = [];
    $summary[] = $this->t('Special daterange formatter.');
    return $summary;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $elements = [];
    $separator = $this->getSetting('separator');

    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
      if (!empty($item->start_date) && !empty($item->end_date)) {
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $start_date */
        $start_date = $item->start_date;
        /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime $end_date */
        $end_date = $item->end_date;

        if ($start_date->getTimestamp() !== $end_date->getTimestamp()) {
          $elements[$delta] = [
            'start_date' => $this->buildDate($start_date),
            'separator' => ['#plain_text' => ' ' . $separator . ' '],
            'end_date' => $this->buildDate($end_date),
          ];
        }
        else {
          $elements[$delta] = $this->buildDate($start_date);
        }
      }
    }

    return $elements;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function settingsForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::settingsForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['date_format'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Date format'),
      '#description' => $this->t('See <a href="http://php.net/manual/function.date.php" target="_blank">the documentation for PHP date formats</a>.'),
      '#default_value' => $this->getSetting('date_format'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

}
```

Comment: `DateTimeCustomFormatter` work with `datetime` field from *Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldFormatter\DateTimeCustomFormatter* you can see 
`*   field_types = {
 *     "datetime"
 *   }`  , but you extended it and you set `field_types = {
 *     "daterange",
 *   }` i think this is the issue.

Comment: I don’t think so. Like I said, this is a clone of the plugins used in the datetime range module. The three plugins it uses look just like this, extend the same way, and work.

Comment: Yes i see, you are right you cloned *core/modules/datetime_range/src/Plugin/Field/FieldFormatter/DateRangeCustomFormatter.php*, i will test you formatter to see what the issue .

Comment: Your formatter work just fine for me, and also `viewElements` triggered, i have `dump` something on it and it's fired try to add `dump('its viewElements method');` clear cache and see if it's dumped ?

Comment: You’re totally right! It’s so strange. I cleared cache umpteen times yesterday, but could get no altered output or debug output. Trying after your message, worked as it should. Must be that it’s Friday! Thanks!!

Comment: Can you write that it worked for you as it should, with a dump too, as an answer?

Comment: You are so welcome, i'm glad that helped, i think no need to post it as an answer.